# how to tunnel SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel, socks

I have a `distant` server, that is not accessible from the outside world. I would like to turn it into a proxy nonetheless. I was thinking I could use `server` (that I fully own) to achieve my goal.

Apologies if the following is not clear enough, for I have very little knowledge about networking.

**What I can do**:

- I know I can open a reverse ssh connexion from `distant` to `server`, and use it to access `distant` from the `local` computer. For instance, from `local` I can `ssh server`, then when logged in, use `ssh localhost -p 12345` to finally access `distant` via ssh.
- I also know about `ssh -D 1080 server`, that will allow me to use `server` as a SOCKS proxy from my computer

[image: network figure]

**What I would like to do**

I would like to open a SOCKS proxy from `local`, that uses the ip of `distant`. I have no idea wether this is possible, but in naive words, I'd say I'm trying to open a socks connexion to the server, while telling the server to use its own localhost:12345 to access internet.

In other words, I'm trying to funnel a SOCKS proxy from `local`to `distant`, thanks to `server` that is accessible via a public IP address.

Any idea/direction on how to do this, provided it is even possible ?

Comment: This worked for me https://superuser.com/a/1530758/111219 It is essentially the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

On `local`:

```
ssh -L 1080:localhost:1080
# now 1080 is listening on `local`
```

On `server`:

```
ssh -D 1080 -p 12345 localhost
# now 1080 is listening on `server`
```

Switch to `autossh` so the connections would persist.